# Extract video clip from MP4 of exacting length

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

The tools I've tried so far are only gives me approximations to the start and end times that I specify. They are usually off by a few seconds.

I need a tool to extract video and audio at exact start and stop times, ideally to the millisecond. It would be preferable to do so without any easily noticeable loss in video quality from the original. I would also prefer to keep the audio in the video.

Comment: A lot of tools can do this, I don't understand why you have a problem with this. e.g. ffmpeg can do this on the millisecond. For mp4, when the cut is not on a I-frame, re-encoding is needed.

Comment: It might not be possible without re-encoding (without any loss in quality), unless lossless video codec is used (I assume it's not counted as a solution). Just in case there is a solution, please make some more effort - post a reproducible example with input and output. Show what you have tried...

Comment: @Poiter I tried ffmpeg but it's a few seconds off like the rest. Maybe I'm using the wrong options on the command line? Can you maybe provide a sample command line of what you're using?

Comment: @Rotem Well I've tried a number of different tools out there. Some people say ffmpeg accomplishes this, but this command line doesn't ffmpeg.exe -ss "0:02.0900" -to "0:05.0100" -i "...\somefile.mp4" test.mp4

Comment: You may try `trim` filter (`-an` is without audio): `ffmpeg -y -an -i somefile.mp4 -vf "trim=start=2.09:duration=2.92,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -vcodec libx264 test.mp4`. The output duration is going to be a multiple of the frame period (if the input rate is 1fps, the accuracy of the output duration is going to be 1 second [rounded to 3 seconds]). There is some loss in quality, because the video is re-encoded. Please do some research, create a reproducible sample and explain the issue more clearly. What do you mean "without any loss in quality"? (do you mean without any visible quality loss?).

Comment: @Rotem I tried it out and I think it works and looks good, at least it seems to work for all the clips I made. A couple things though. Is it possible to set times for start and end, rather than duration? And any way to keep the sound? Thanks man

Comment: There is `start` and `end`. Use `ffmpeg -h filter=trim` for list of options. For audio, use `atrim` filter and `asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS` (remove the `-an`). The reason I removed the audio, is that the audio stream may be the reason for the inaccurate length. I am still expecting a reproducible example. Use an input video file from [here](https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/) maybe... Explain what tool you are using for getting the duration. Show FFmpeg command you have tried.

Comment: @Rotem could you provide a sample command line? Much appreciated again thanks

Comment: I want to post an answer, instead of keep commenting. I am waiting for you to update the question...

Comment: @Rotem Go ahead and post the answer. What would you like me to update it with?

Comment: Your reputation score is above 1000... do you want me to refer you to the "how to ask a question" tutorial (in case you are sharing your account with other user, please read the [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))? Please read my previous comments for figuring out what to update.

Comment: @Rotem I'm guessing you're referring to the loss in quality stuff? That's no biggie, I just don't want such a loss in video quality that it is all that noticeable. But if there is a loss in quality, it appears to be acceptable to me. In my case I would also rather keep the sound than not, but I can do without if need be. It is low priority. The main thing I need is the clip to match the exact start and end times I specify to ideally the millisecond (but tenth of a second suffices).

Comment: @Rotem the answer you've given sufficiently answers my question, please go ahead and post and I'll give you the 50 reputuation. The clips appear to match the start and end times I specify and I don't notice any substantial loss in quality. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @Rotem the only thing I would change in the answer you post is maybe instead of providing duration, specifying start and end times but providing the end time is only a convenience. In essence, you have resolved my issue.

Comment: My minimum request is that you make a **reproducible** example of the problem you are describing.

Comment: @wes I edited your question (based on the comments here) and answered it. Please let me know if I incorrectly understood your question **or** the answer does not satisfy your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this [test video](https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-30s.mp4), I cut a 4 and a half second chunk of video and audio out and into a `new.mp4` with this:

```
ffmpeg -i sample-30s.mp4 -filter:v "trim=8.25:12.75,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -filter:a "atrim=8.25:12.75,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -vcodec libx264 new.mp4
```

The various options mean:

- `-filter:v` is to filter video and `-filter:a` is the same for audio.
- [`trim=`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim) and [`atrim=`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) specify the start and stop time for the cut to make.
- `setpts=` and `asetpts=` apply the [PTS-STARTPTS filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts) to change the timestamps to 0:00 in the output file.
- `-vcodec libx264` uses the x264 library.

The [timestamps](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax) can take many forms such as '23.189' for 23.189 seconds, ‘12:03:45’ for 12 hours, 03 minutes and 45 seconds, and 200000 microseconds for 0.2s.

You need the setpts/asetpts option to reset timestamps, as [explained here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

> Be aware that frames are taken from each input video in timestamp order, hence, if their initial timestamps differ, it is a good idea to pass the two inputs through a setpts=PTS-STARTPTS filter to have them begin in the same zero timestamp, as the example for the movie filter does.